# Airflow list_dags not identifying dag with variable

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to run `airflow list_dags` and I'm getting:

```
[2020-11-12 09:42:09,617] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2020-11-12 09:42:09,618] {{dagbag.py:403}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2020-11-12 09:42:09,692] {{dagbag.py:246}} ERROR - Failed to import: /usr/local/airflow/dags/my-dag/my_dag.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: variable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 243, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/my-dag/my_dag.py", line 22, in <module>
    my_conf = Variable.get("my_conf", deserialize_json=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

I understand airflow is not able to recognize the variable `my_conf`. How can I set this variable from the airflow cli? Or, how can I make `airflow list_dags` work even if there's a variable I have not set? I have the same issue if the variable is set from the ui.

Comment: Could you provide the code of the DAG? Otherwise it's quite hard to give any useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this'll solve your problem, as the error seems to indicate a different problem, but to answer your concrete question:

```
airflow variables -s my_conf some_value
```

This can be found in the [CLI documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/cli.html#variables).